# Как использовать цикл do-while для подсчёта положительных и отрицательных чисел в массиве?

Tags: java, циклы

Нужна программа которая читает с клавиатуры числа пока не вводим 0 и определяет сколько положительных и отрицательных чисел были введены

```
int[] a = {8, 2, 7, -2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 9, -3, -6, -8, -1, -4, -5, -7, -9};
System.out.println("Массив целых чисел:\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

System.out.println("\nОтрицательные числа:");
for (int value : a) {
   if (value < 0) {
      System.out.println(value);
   }
}

System.out.println("\nПоложительные числа числа:");
for (int value : a) {
   if (value >= 0) {
      System.out.println(value);
   }
}

System.out.println("\nСортировка по возрастанию:\n");
Arrays.sort(a);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: ну так напишите ее, раз Вам нужна, а если что не получится - пишите сюда, поможем

Comment: дело в том что у меня не получается,всякие методы искал но не то

Comment: нажмите на кнопку **править** и добавьте код, который Вы уже написали до этого...

Comment: вот это что я пробовал но тут без циклов do,while да и результат должен быть другим.Мне нужно чтоб вывести на экран положительные числа: n количество и отрицательные: n количество

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить переменную-счетчик и выход из цикла при равенстве нулю, как-то так:

```
int[] a = {8, 2, 7, -2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 9, -3, -6, -8, -1, -4, -5, -7, -9};
System.out.println("Массив целых чисел:\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

int countNegative = 0;
int countPositive = 0;
for (int value : a) {
   if (value < 0) {
      countNegative++;
   } else if(value > 0) {
      countPositive++;
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
System.out.println("\nОтрицательные числа:" + countNegative);
System.out.println("\Положительные числа:" + countPositive);

System.out.println("\nСортировка по возрастанию:\n");
Arrays.sort(a);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Scanner systemInScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = -1;
    int pozCount = 0; //количество положительных чисел
    int negCount = 0; //количество отрицательных чисел
    while(number != 0){
        number = systemInScanner.nextInt();
        if(number > 0) pozCount++;
        else if (number < 0) negCount++;
    }
```